# Improper format of Registration Form in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

Right now, I'm working on the registration form in Django. In my registration form, there is the total of six fields like Username, First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, Password Confirmation. During my testing of the registration form, I figured out such a weird thing. Every time fields change their positions. I mean sometime Password comes at first place and Last Name at last place. And whenever I shut down the server and run it again then again fields positions changed again.

See below some screenshot. So you can understand what I mean to say.

[image: Image1]

And If I shut down the server and run it again then

[image: Image2]

It happens every time. According to the logic which I write in the code it must in one proper manner like  Username, First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, Password Confirmation.

Here below my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm

# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()    
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

And below one is forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Where did you put the info about the password (currently your code fragment does not have this).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Here, I used the django.contrib.auth.forms and import the UserCreationForm. so it appears automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are declaring the fields in your form as a set and not as a list. Declare it as a list and everything will be in the order your define.

That will make your code look like:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        ]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

A very minute change, but it should do the trick.